# (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' ([Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: python, mysql, docker, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to Dockerize a FastAPI app that uses MYSQL and Seleniun.

I am having issues with connecting MYSQL with the FASTAPI app in the Docker.
I have tried to establish connection with MYSQL container using MYSQL Workbench which worked well using 'localhost' as the host. However, when I try to run the fastapi container which should connect with MySqL database, I am having this error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' ([Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`

Here is docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  chrome:
    build: .
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-20210929
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      - "5900:5900"
    volumes:
      - "/dev/shm:/dev/shm"
    networks:
      - selenium
    

  
  mysql:
     image: mysql:8.0
     command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password 
     restart: always
     environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=autojob
       - MYSQL_USER=user
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=4444
     healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
            timeout: 20s
            retries: 10
     volumes:
       - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
       - autojob:/var/lib/mysql
     ports:
       - "3307:3306"
     expose:
       - "3307"
    


  app:
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: "autojobserve_container"
    command:
      uvicorn autojobserve.app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - "./:/app"
    networks:
      - selenium
    depends_on:
      mysql:
          condition: service_healthy



volumes:
  autojob: {}

networks:
  selenium:
```

Here is the line that connects with MYSQL in FastAPI:
`engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:4444@mysql:3307/autojob")`

In DockerDesktop, it shows that Mysql container is ready for connection too:

```
2022-11-08T11:49:26.334069Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-11-08T11:49:26.334869Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-11-08 11:49:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.31-1.el8 started.
2022-11-08 11:49:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-11-08 11:49:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.31-1.el8 started.
'/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

What possibly could be wrong?
Note: Everything works well before dockerizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app` container declares `networks: [selenium]`.  The `mysql` container doesn't have a `networks:` block at all, so Compose automatically inserts `networks: [default]`.  Since the two containers aren't on the same Docker network they can't communicate with each other, and one of the ways you see that is with the DNS-resolution issue you're seeing.

The setup I'd recommend here is to delete *all* of the `networks:` blocks in the whole file.  Compose will [automatically](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) create the `default` network and attach containers to it, and for most applications this is a correct setup.

(You also do not need the obsolete `expose:` option, or to manually specify `container_name:`.  You should not need to use `volumes:` to inject code into your container or `command:` either, the code and its default command should generally be specified in the Dockerfile.)

Comment: Thank you, David. I have applied these changes you mentioned. Now I have this as an  error ```sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)```

Comment: The standard MySQL port is 3306, not 3307, and you need to use that port number in your connection string.  Connections between containers do not use or require `ports:`.